# Integral is zero; is the integrand necessarily odd?

Tags: integration, continuity, exponential-function, fourier-series, even-and-odd-functions

As we know, the integral of an odd (integrable) function over a symmetric interval disappears. Now, I am having difficulties about proving a somewhat converse statement of this, specifically:

Let $f$ be a continuous, $2\pi$-periodic function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\,e^{\,ikx} \; dx \; = \; 0$ for all even $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that f is an odd function.

I am not even sure if this statement holds. Maybe there is a counterexample which I don't see right now.

Comment: Nope. counterexample: $f(x) = \cos x$.

Comment: Oh yes, that's right. Did you simply guess?

Comment: I start by expressing $f(x)$ in its Fourier transform and then notice there isn't enough $k$ to force $f(x)$ to be odd.

Comment: @achillehui Please write that up as an answer, not a comment.